# Wordpress Contact Form Spam protection with Google Captcha and Honey Pot

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, spam, spam-prevention

I have set up a contact form with contact form 7 and Contact Form 7 Captcha (google reCAPTCHA v2) and honey pot (Honeypot for Contact Form 7) and still getting spam mostly in russian language.

Recaptcha stats show, that most spam is sorted out, but one or two per day gets trough.
[image: Recaptcha success rate]

My Wordpress form:

```
[honeypot honeypot-442 id:first-name-field]
<label> Name*
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> E-Mail*
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject*
    [text* your-subject] </label>

<label> Message*
    [textarea* your-message] </label>

[cf7sr-simple-recaptcha]

[submit "Submit"]
```

How can I make my contact form spam free?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem (10+ sites small to enterprise). The solution we found that works best was an API called Bot Butcher. There is another API called Akismet, but we found it to be less accurate. The idea with both is you take the message and classify it with these APIs before sending the message on to their final destination (email inbox, Hubspot, etc). We ended up removing Recaptcha altogether because it was not effective and it became unnecessary to have that human challenge speed bump.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Wp Form which better than contact form 7 and it will also spammers quite better